# vectorized if-else for multiple block commands

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm looking for a way to perform multiple variable assignments based on a single conditional statement. The ifelse function performs what I want for a single variable at a time, but I'd like to be able to perform a block of statements based on a single condition.

Here is a bit of simplified example code:

```
within(mydata, {
  if (gender == "f") {
    test1 <- 1
    test2 <- 2
  } else {
    test1 <- 0
    test2 <- 0
  }
  test3 <- gender
  test4 <- ifelse(gender == "f", 1, 0)
  test5 <- ifelse(gender == "f", 2, 0)  
})
```

Which gives the following output:

```
  workshop gender q1 q2 q3 q4 test5 test4 test3 test2 test1
1        1      f  1  1  5  1     2     1     f     2     1
2        2      f  2  1  4  1     2     1     f     2     1
3        1      f  2  2  4  3     2     1     f     2     1
4        2      f  3  1 NA  3     2     1     f     2     1
5        1      m  4  5  2  4     0     0     m     2     1
6        2      m  5  4  5  5     0     0     m     2     1
7        1      m  5  3  4  4     0     0     m     2     1
8        2      m  4  5  5  5     0     0     m     2     1
Warning message:
In if (gender == "f") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

When I run this code, test4 and test5 are correctly assigned, but test1 and test2 are incorrectly assigned, because the if statement returns the value for the first row only. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do with test1 and test2 - run multiple statements for each row of a data frame based on a single condition?

I know I can accomplish the same result with ifelse, but I'd like to be able to group the statements together, for clarity when reading my code.

For example, I'd like to be able to group the savings calculations that I do by measure, as follows:

```
a.lighting.all.3 <- within(a.lighting.all.3, {
  if (measure.subcategory %in% c('HID to Linear Fluorescent Retrofit', 
                                 'Hardwired CFL', 'Induction Lighting', 
                                 'Screw-In CFL', 'Specialty Screw-In CFL',
                                'T12 to Premium T8/T5', 'T12 to Standard T8/T5',
                                 'T8 to Premium T8', 'T12/T8 Delamping')) {
    kw.nc.v <- (base.watts - ee.watts) / 1000 * (1 + dif) * df * quantity
    kwh.v <- (base.watts - ee.watts) / 1000 * (1 + eif) * op.hrs * quantity    
  } else if (measure.subcategory == 'Traffic Signals') {
    kw.nc.v <- (base.watts - ee.watts) / 1000 * quantity
    kwh.v <- (base.watts - ee.watts) / 1000 * op.hrs * quantity    
  } else if (measure.subcategory == 'Exit Sign Retrofit') {

  } else if (measure.subcategory %in% c('LED Channel Lights',
                                        'Cold Cathode FL')) {
  } else if (measure.subcategory %in% c('Daylighting Controls', 
                                        'Occupancy Sensors')) {

  } else if (measure.subcategory == 'Lighting Power Density') {

  } else if (measure.subcategory == 'LED Lighting') {

  }
})
```

Or assign sets of parameters by measure, such as:

```
a.lighting.all.3 <- within(a.lighting.all.3, {
  switch(as.character(measure.subcategory),
     "T8 to Premium T8" = {
       op.hrs <- 4481
       cf <- 0.93
     },
     "Cold Cathode FL" = {
       op.hrs <- 6400
       cf <- 1
     },
     "Exit Sign Retrofit" = {
       op.hrs <- 8760
       cf <- 1
     },
     "LED Channel Lights" = {
       op.hrs <- 5110
       cf <- 0.134
     },
     "Traffic Signals" = {
       op.hrs <- ifelse(grepl("Green", measure), 3679, 4818)
       df <- ifelse(grepl("Green", measure), 0.42, 0.55)
       cf <- 1
     },
     "Daylighting Controls" = {
       dsf <- esf <-  0.54  # daylight savings fraction
     },
     "Occupancy Sensors" = {
       dsf <- 0.16  # demand savings fraction
       esf <- 0.39  # energy savings fraction
     },
     "LED Lighting" = {
       if (measure %in% c("Pedestrian NO countdown", 
                          "Pedestrian W/ countdown")) {
         cf <- 1
         op.hrs <- ifelse(measure == "Pedestrian W/ countdown", 6483, 5432)
         op.hrs.base <- 5432
         df <- ifelse(measure == "Pedestrian W/ countdown", 0.74, 0.62)
         df.base <- 0.62
       } else if (measure %in% c("Refrigerated Case LED Lamps NO motion Sensors",
                                 "Refrigerated Case LED Lamps W/ motion Sensors")) {
         cf <- 1
         dif <- 0.25
         eif <- 0.25
         op.hrs.base <- 8634
         op.hrs <- ifelse(measure == "Refrigerated Case LED Lamps W/ motion Sensors",
                          6043, 8634)
       }
     }
  )
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what is so bad about four `ifelse` calls; it is IMHO a lot clearer than the solutions provided so far. If it is repeating the `gender == "f"` part that you find too repetitive, you could assign it to a `is.female` variable.

Comment: Also, since your "else" values are all `0`, then you could use type conversions, e.g. `test2 <- 2 * (gender == "f")` but it's not as clear as `ifelse` in my opinion.

Comment: @flodel: My actual application is much more complex than my original example, and would result in a bunch of ifelse statements. I've added examples of what I'm trying to do above - any additional thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Your project looks more and more like it should use multiple tables/map (data.frames or data.tables) so you can join your data using tools like `merge`.

Comment: That's a good point. I've done that with the standard values of these parameters - these ones were the special cases. But I suppose it's easier to just create another lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d <- data.frame(workshop=rep(1:2,4),
                gender=rep(c("f","m"),each=4))
```

I don't know if this answer makes you happy or not, but: if you use `plyr` to operate on *blocks* of code you can do what you want with an `if` statement.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d,"gender",
      function(x) {
          within(x, {
              test3 <- gender
              ## test FIRST value only, since by construction they
              ## are all the same within a piece
              if (gender[1]=="f") {
                  test1 <- 1
                  test2 <- 2
                  test4 <- 1
                  test5 <- 1
              } else {
                  test1 <- test2 <- test4 <- test5 <- 0
              }})
      })
```

Note that this will rearrange your data into blocks by gender (in this example it doesn't change anything), which might be undesirable ...

I didn't include the additional variables in my example, but they will get carried along correctly.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! You're right, it's not the most efficient way to do things, but I think the improvement in read-ability of my code was worth it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A data.table solution for time and memory efficiency and elegance of coding

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(d)

DT[,  `:=`(paste0('test',1:5), list((1:0)[gender],  
            (c(2,0))[gender], gender, (1:0)[gender], (1:0)[gender])), with = F]
```

`:=` will assign by reference and can work for multiple columns if the `LHS` argument is a character vector of names (to be created) and the RHS is a list with the values to be used.

This solution also utilises the fact that `gender` is a factor variable, and we can use the underlying integer values to reference the recoding.

you could also do something like

```
setkey(|Dt, gender)
DT['f', test1 := 1]
DT['m', test1 := 0]
DT['f', test2 := 2]
DT['m', test2 := 0]
DT[,test3 := gender]
# etc
```

This will  give warnings if gender is factor not character, but will still work.

Comment: I'm not sure the `:=(paste0...)` way could be called _elegant_ really, but I like the 2nd way. Would benefit from multiple `:=` in `j` when implemented.